# Problem with 2d texture import in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, textures

so I am facing a strange problem I have JPG file I wanted to import to unity 3d which I did here is the image of the settings that it was imported with...

[image]
<sub>(source: [internetseekho.com](https://internetseekho.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Screenshot_3.png))</sub>

Once the image got imported I create a new Raw image and imported this as a texture to it up until this everything is fine...

[image]
<sub>(source: [internetseekho.com](https://internetseekho.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Screenshot_2.png))</sub>

After this once I change the UV Rect width or height its just get everything messed up...

[image]
<sub>(source: [internetseekho.com](https://internetseekho.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Screenshot_4.png))</sub>

So am I doing something wrong or is there any problem with my unity 3d and I have to update it...

Answer (score 1):

In the import settings of the texture change `Wrap Mode` to `Repeat`.